# Is there a package/function that returns timezone when fed a US State in R

Tags: r, timezone

I am wondering if there is an effective function or package in R that returns the time zone of the state that is fed into it. For example, if you fed the function "CA", it would return with "PST" or "Pacific".

```
>function("CA")
>"PST"
```

Thanks

Comment: You should rephrase your question into "how can I get the timezone from...", and you may have answers about external packages or not, questions that ask for a package are closed.

Comment: [Some states have more than one time zone](https://www.thoughtco.com/states-split-into-two-time-zones-4072169).

Comment: Dup is asking about PHP, but the question is the same, and so is the answer.  No - it cannot be done because several states have more than one time zone.  You will need [latitude and longitude coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086962/how-to-get-a-time-zone-from-a-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates) to resolve a time zone.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some code like this, if you have a list of what results you want for each state (taking account of MrFlick's commment).

```
library(dplyr)
case_when(
  x %in% c("1", "2", "3") ~ "Central Time", 
  x %in% c("4", "5", "6") ~ "Pacific Time", 
)
```

Here, 1,2,3 would be the names of states and you can add time zones as necessary.